# Why Airy disk (Fraunhofer diffraction) is first order of the Bessel function of the first kind?

Tags: optics, wavefunction, diffraction, microscopy

I have been studying Fourier ptychography.
I am confused about why Airy disk is J1 of the Bessel function. I think that Fraunhofer diffraction looks more like J0 of the Bessel function.

[image: Gris-Sánchez (2016)]

[image: Bessel function of the first kind]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the Bessel function itself, instead it's proportional to a ratio of the Bessel function and its argument. This turns the first-order zero of the $J_1$ at $x=0$ into a constant as $x\to0,$ i.e. the behavior similar to that of $J_0.$ See the difference between these functions:

[image]

Comment: out of interest: what software did you use to create the nice graph?

Comment: @AndrewSteane Wolfram Mathematica

Comment: @AndrewSteane With LaTeX you can do much nicer plots, with better axes and legends, and in a pdf the image doesn't get grainy when you zoom in. For function that are not composed with elementary function (ex. Bessel, Riemann, gamma, etc.) it is sufficient to have a txt file with many values in the interval you want to plot (using smooth option).

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro thanks, I use LaTeX and tikz for documents but in this example it is speed of going from a standing start to a nice output which I care about

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro there are more options (e.g. matplotlib+scipy), but regarding scalability, this site doesn't support SVG, unfortunately, so it's useless even if your toolkit is capable of it.

Comment: @Ruslan Of course I know, that's why I wrote *in a pdf* the image doesn't get grainy. I think these solution are very elegant in making pdf, but maybe in Stack Exchange I agree that for plots (not for equations) it is better the most practical solution of pasting jpg.

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro oh no, not JPEG! PNG is way better for these purposes.

Comment: @Ruslan oh..  thank you so much. It is quite clear.